# Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse Mars menu problem

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, menu

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and I had a problem with the main menu not showing.
I solved it by running Eclipse with `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` and the menu is visible but now I have another problem. Some of the options in the menu don't work.
For example the `Window`->`Preferences` only shows the General page and I can't select any other option.

[image: Image of the broken menu]

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Your `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` tip fixed my problem! I added `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /.../eclipse` to my shortcut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to start Eclipse after editing your `eclipse.ini` file and tweaking the `launcher` entry like this:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Example file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822242/eclipse-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-16-04/36859485

Comment: This answer in your link worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36825434/193708. Thanks

Comment: This didn't work for me. It actually made the problem even worse.

Comment: Worked with Eclipse Neon.2 for J2EE on Xubuntu 16.04.