# Eclipse IDE missing icons and menus

Tags: eclipse, 16.10

I've an issue with Eclipse Neon, my daily development platform.
After the upgrade to 16.10 my Eclipse shows less icons than it normally does.
Most of the tool bar icons are missing and also perspective selector is missing, that usually it is on the right corner of the window.

Could someone please help me? I already tried some newer versions of Eclipse, like Neon1 and Oxygen, but they does fix the issue. I assume the problem is related to GTK, can I switch back to a previous version?

Many thanks if you will help me, I will appreciate it a lot.

[image: Here it is a screen of my current tool bar]

Comment: Worked for me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/763256/ubuntu-16-04-and-eclipse-mars-menu-problem

Answer (score 22):

in **eclipse.ini**

insert

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

Comment: I already tried this solution, it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Run Eclipse with the `clearPersistedState` option:

```
eclipse -clearPersistedState
```

The toolbar will be shown again, but you will lose some UI state, like the list of open files.

Comment: This worked after I lost my buttons when upgrading from Neon to Oxygen. I also got a StackOverflowError when trying to access `Customize Perspective`

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. I didn't get the eclipse.ini solution to work either.

I tested the suggested solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822242/eclipse-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-16-04/36825434#36825434

export SWT_GTK3=0
./eclipse

That fixed it for me. There are a few graphics issues with the dark theme, but good enough to work with.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone thinking about switching to Ubuntu 17.04 with eclipse "*Oxygen*": changing the eclipse.ini to ...

--launcher.GTK_version

2

works fine but only when its launched from the terminal.

To make it even work from the launcher Icon in the sidebar open *.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop* and Change the line starting with *Exec=.....* to *Exec=eclipse*